# Find the highest number from a user input list

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("enter the element in list")
list1=input().split()

print(list1)
max = 0
for i in list1:
    if max < int(i):
        max = i

print(f"The maximum number in list is {max} ")
```

The error I get is:

> if max < int(i): TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of
>   'str' and 'int'

Comment: Max also must be an int : `max = i` => `max = int(i)`

Comment: I did typecast max to int, but shouldn't max already be considered as integer as I am assigning 0 to max

Comment: you assign a string to max: `max = i` after your first check.

Comment: `print( max( map ( int, input().split() ) ) )` witll print the max number if you input space seperated numbers

Answer (score 0):

`int(i)` will not have any effect on value of `i`. Instead it will create a new variable in memory and value of `i` will remain unchanged which would still be a string. So `max` will be assigned string value when you do `max = i`

Instead you should do

```
max = int(i)
```

Comment: `for int(i) in list1:` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Several things :

Do not shadow built-in method name (here `max`)

The problem here is your assignement : `max = i`, max becomes a string.

You can either be careful while assigning or convert everything to `int`.

```
max = int(i)
```

or `list1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Last but not least, you can do it with the `max` built-in. `max(l)`

Comment: Thanks man..I just started learning python and i really did not know                                       [int(i) for i in input().split()]          was possible

Comment: @AbhishekDiwate, my pleasure ! Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it helped you :) (the tick on the left side)